# org-mode: fontify code blocks natively

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I can't get org-mode to fontify code blocks the way it should...I'm using Gnu Emacs 23.3.1 on cygwin and I tried it on same version WinNT. In my init file:

```
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
```

Then I expect blocks like this to fontified like sql-mode:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql

SELECT * FROM foo;

#+END_SRC
```

The contents of the block are shown in a different face to normal text, but no keyword highlighting etc. The same goes for other languages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My org-mode is too old (6.33x, which ships with my Emacs). This feature requires 7.x. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: You should delete the question then if you can.

Comment: @Tom it seems I can't delete it because I answered it -- sorry about that. I suppose it might be useful to someone else who hasn't RTFM.

Comment: yep it was useful to me so don't delete it :-)